# why Laravel @yield and @section not wokring?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have Master as a main page where I load dynamic pages.
***Master***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
@include('backend.includes.header')
@yield('style')
</head>
<body>
   
@include('backend.includes.navbar')


<div class="mobile-menu-overlay"></div>
@yield('content')

@yield('script')
</body>
</html>
```

***Dashboard***

```
@extends('backend.master.master')
@section('style')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/css/apexcharts.css') }}">
@stop
@section('content')
// Dashboard Code here
@endsection
@section('script')
<script src="{{ asset('backend/js/dashboard.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

It doesn't render `@yield('style')` and `@yield('script')`

Also my controller:

```
 public function index(){
    return view('backend.pages.home.dashboard');
}
```

Comment: why do you have @stop in your dashboard blade file?

Comment: @JibinBose I replaced it with endsection. Doesn't work either

Comment: `@stop` is an alternative to `@endsection`, isn't seen in newer versions of Laravel, but is still available for compatibility reasons.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What exactly does it do? Do you see anything? Everything you would expect except the things you point out as missing? 

What are the names and paths of the files you are showing above?